# Where XEN stores the boot logs (Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, xen

I have some failure during my boot of Xen 4.* on Ubuntu 13.*, it shows some error info on the screen, but I can't look at it because it scrolls down several screens during the printing, and also reboots automatically after 5 second. Where can I look at the stored logs of the Xen boot?

Answer (score 0):

Well what you can do is boot from a **live CD**, and check

`/var/log/boot, /var/log/syslog , /var/log/messages and /var/log/dmesg` including the **.gz** files for errors

i hope this helps :)

Comment: Hmm.. I don't have a live-cd near me right now, but I can boot to regular Ubuntu without Xen and read these files. But their are either overwritten by the normal boot, or didn't contain any Xen logs in the first place, because I can't find anything relevant there.

Comment: yes, when you would reboot with regular ubuntu then the logs might get lost. You somehow have to recover the logs without booting from your hard drive...

Comment: how about you use slax ...i am recommending this because its very small in size and you can download it in no time even if you have a slow internet connection and then boot from a usb drive.http://www.slax.org/